# Checkbox with Catel EventToCommand not working in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, catel

I have the following XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
      </CheckBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In the viewmodels I have;

```
public Command UpdateCommand { get; private set; }
UpdateCommand = new Command(UpdateControls);

private void UpdateControls()
{
    //Execute
}
```

However, UpdateControls is never executed. Can anybody help me with this to get this working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to yourself (which is the CheckBox). You should give the DataGrid a name and then use this binding:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Command="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=DataContext.UpdateCommand}" />
```